# FeynArts is not plotting Propagator labels/fields

Tags: feyncalc, drawing

I am trying to use FeynArts to generate two feynman diagrams (one for electron scattering, and one for higgs->bb w/ VGF). On the first I can't seem to figure out how to get labels or arrows, not get the photon to display correctly.

```
TopologyList[
 Topology[2][
  Propagator[Incoming][Vertex[1][1], Vertex[4][2], F[2, {1}]],
  Propagator[Outgoing][Vertex[1][3], Vertex[4][2]],
  Propagator[Incoming][Vertex[1][4], Vertex[4][5]], 
  Propagator[Outgoing][Vertex[1][6], Vertex[4][5]],
  Propagator[Internal][Vertex[4][2], Vertex[4][5] , V[1]]
  ]]
```

I have tried using PropagatorGraphics, but had no luck with that.